# Issues with IE8 when applying Position: fixed

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Here's my css code:

```
background-color: White;
border: 2px solid black;
padding: 10px;
position: fixed;
right: 5px;
top: 0;
width: 250px;
```

It works great in Chrome/Firefox/Safari, but I can't get it working in IE8. The position of div box isn't not in the top right corner. Any ideas on how I can solve this problem?

Along with the HTML

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;right:5px;background-color:White;padding:10px;border:2px black solid;width:250px;">
  <div>content here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @kinakuta I have updated my questions. You can find html there. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this in the very top of the document above the header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually fixed a lot of problems I had with a webpage in IE. Could you please explain why this works? Does this have to do with the webpage headers the request sends?

Comment: It tells the browser which HTML definition to use.  (e.g. HTML4, HTML5, etc).  Each browser has a default definition to use if none is specified.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration