# position:fixed(css) behaving differently in different browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I am trying to freeze the table header.. in order to achieve the same I have written [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xDcLa/) code.. it works fine but header seems to shivering.

So I changed a code little bit and output is pretty good now, you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Newuser123/yGPcm/).
But the problem is, this changed code works in Mozilla but not in IE.
I tried multiple approach but couldn't get the exact behaviour in IE as it is in second fiddle.
In second fiddle, in side doc ready I have changed existing code with this one-

```
 var originalHeaderRow = $("tr:eq(1)", this)
        originalHeaderRow.before(originalHeaderRow.clone());
        var clonedHeaderRow = $("tr:eq(1)", this)
        clonedHeaderRow.addClass("tableFloatingHeader");
        clonedHeaderRow.css("position", "fixed");
        clonedHeaderRow.css("top", $("tr:eq(1)").css("top"));
        var left = $("tr:eq(1)").offset().left;
        clonedHeaderRow.css("left", left);
```

Any suggestion or any hint where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of placing the floatingHeaderRow into the table, place it in the body with a fixed position.  This way it isn't constantly having to calculate a new position.

Something like this, but not perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/NtBYa/2/

Comment: you are talking about table body or page body

Comment: page body `$('body').before(originalHeaderRow.clone());`

Comment: even my original header fade out on page load with this approach

Comment: I just edited the jsfiddle link, that should make it a little clearer.

Comment: +1 for your efforts, i got your words but the problem is i am having many div sections in my body, then i am having table.so if i append it on body, it will get appended before those div and while showing it it would be sit above those div not on table..hope you might get what i am saying

Comment: That is why you use `$(window).scrollTop()` to make sure it only happens when you are scrolled down far enough and `$('table tr:eq(1)').offset().top` to figure out exactly how far down that is.

Comment: For instance, here's the same jsfiddle I posted except with a couple elements before the table.  http://jsfiddle.net/NtBYa/3/

Comment: yeah you are right even i have done the same thing to check it out, but it's again works well but only in firefox not in IE.

Comment: Not seeing anything different in IE, please explain.

Comment: i copy paste your jsfiddle code in notepad, save it as `test.html`, ran it on firefox works well , ran on IE header didn't get freeze.even there is no error on ie

Comment: might be because you're not using the right doctype, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435867/issues-with-ie8-when-applying-position-fixed/6435957#6435957

Comment: hmm, don't know what to tell you, the jsfiddle works in ie, so you must be doing something different

Comment: same here man..even i am not getting why it's not happening in ie...for testing purpose i have created a simple html with only those things which is required in my case..added right doctype at top as suggested by you...but still i left with no hope

Comment: if you load local html files in IE sometimes it does not allow scripts to be run, you may need to run it through a web server.