# Follow me menu - CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to have a menu that follows my user when they scroll down a screen, but it my code below doesnt seem to work.  Any suggestions:

```
    <html> 
<head></head> 
<body style="height:2000px;"> <div style="position:fixed;right:0px; width:100px; height:200px; top:100px;     background-color:blue;">
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Works fine here. What browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/UrFE9/

Comment: It works when I copy/paste that and try it.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Seems fine.

Comment: It should work according to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed).

Comment: Apparently it is due to the doctype, but this problem is described (and solved) in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435867/issues-with-ie8-when-applying-position-fixed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to fix a position for IE, here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:2000px;">
  <div id="menu1" style="position:absolute;right:0px; width:100px; height:200px; top:100px; background-color:blue;"> </div>
</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = updatePosition;
window.onresize = updatePosition;

function getScrollTop()
{
    if(typeof pageYOffset != 'undefined')
    {
        //most browsers except IE before #9
        return pageYOffset;
    }
    else
    {
        var B = document.body; //IE 'quirks'
        var D = document.documentElement; //IE with doctype
        D = (D.clientHeight) ? D : B;
        return D.scrollTop;
    }
}

function updatePosition()
{
    document.getElementById("menu1").style.top = getScrollTop()+100;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use jQuery animation for smooth scroll :)